# OAuth2 Authentication failed of .net core api call fails using Msal.js on a React-Typescript web app

Tags: c#, typescript, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have a client Typescript React web application that needs to communicate with a .net core api. On client the msal.js was integrated. I am able to login in AAD, get the user account and the access token and pass it as a Bearer to the api call. However the authentication on api level fails.

**On Client:**

```js
config: Msal.Configuration = buildConfiguration({ auth: {
        clientId: 'clientId',
        authority: 'authority',
        validateAuthority: true,
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false
    } });

 request = {
        scopes: ["user.read"] 
     };

    userAgentApp : Msal.UserAgentApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(this.config);

private _accessToken: string = '';
    public async GetAccessToken(): Promise<string>{
        if(this._accessToken == '')
        {
            await this.userAgentApp.acquireTokenSilent(this.request)
                .then((tokenResponse) => this._accessToken = tokenResponse.accessToken)
                .catch((error) => console.log(error))
        }

        return this._accessToken;
    }

    public login() {
        console.log("before login");

        this.userAgentApp.handleRedirectCallback((error, response) => 
        { 
            console.error(error)
        });

        this.userAgentApp.loginRedirect(this.request);

        console.log("after login")
    }

// Calling the api
  axios.defaults.headers.common = {'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`}
      const travelExpensesResponse = await axios.get("https://localhost:44350/api/reisekostenantrag")
```

**On Api**

```
// Start.cs ConfigureServices
  services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
 .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Audience = "clientId";
                options.Authority = "authority";
            });
```

I am gettting a SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException: IDX10511: Signature validation failed.

1. Where could be the problem?
2. Are there any samples to show how can I pass a token to .net core api from a client app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the token was given this scope `user.read` which is a Graph API scope.

So the solution was to register the server app in azure and create a [custom scope](https://tsmatz.wordpress.com/2017/06/22/web-api-and-custom-scope-with-azure-ad-v2-endpoint/).

Then on client app:

```
 request = {
        scopes: ["api://clientid/access_as_user"] 
     };
```